# adding dynamic/multiple slug values in 'option_none_value'

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, wp-query, functions

I am working on a wordpress website and i am little stuck into one situation, what i want is that to add multiple and dynamic slug values from job listing taxonomy, right now i have to manually insert the slug name into `'option_none_value'  => '',` if no category is selected. I searched a lot on google but didn't find any relevant solution.

```php
wp_dropdown_categories( 
    array(
        'show_option_none'   => 'All Job-types',
        'option_none_value'  => '',
        'value_field'       => 'slug',
        'taxonomy'          => 'job_listing_type',
        'name'              => 'search_type',
        'orderby'           => 'name',
        'class'             => 'select-on-home',
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'hide_empty'        => true ,
        'show_option_all'   => esc_html__('','workscout'),
        'echo' => 0
    )
);
```

[image]

Comment: When you say you want  to dynamically insert the value, where is the value coming from? I'm not sure what it is that you want to insert. Can you explain? Is it the current term of the current archive?

Comment: @TomJNowell i need the list of slugs of my job types. i added a screenshot up, check please

Comment: If you want to query jobs that have _any_ type, then you shouldn't need a value at all. Just don't query by job type unless one is selected.